# best practice for thread safe session bean in spring?

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, thread-safety

I'm wondering what is the best practice for making a session bean thread safe.

Let's assume I have this session bean and its service:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class Cart {

    private HashSet<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

    private int counter = 0;

    public HashSet<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

}

@Service
class CartService {

    @Autowired
    private Cart cart;

    public void addItem(Item item) throws FullException {
        if (cart.getCounter() > 1234) {
            throw new FullException();

        }
        cart.getItems().add(item);
    }

}
```

The code above is not thread safe and will cause issues when multiple threads (of the same session, eg. by asynchronous Ajax-requests) perform a `CartService.addItem(Item)`.

I think I'm not the first with this problem, but my researches didn't bring me to a best practice.

The worst thing I could do would synchronize addItem() as CartService is shared by multiple sessions. Synchronizing on cart in `CartService.addItem()` seems to me similarly bad, as Cart is a proxied bean. Which I understand as all sessions would still synchronize on the same object.

One acceptable solution seems to be a synchronized block on `Cart.getItems()` in `CartService.addItem()`:

```
@Service
class CartService {

    @Autowired
    private Cart cart;

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        synchronized(cart.getItems()) {
            if (cart.getCounter() > 1234) {
                throw new FullException();

            }
            cart.getItems().add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Is there any best practice? Maybe spring has something to offer for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a bit through the Spring API I found `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.setSynchronizeOnSession(boolean)` which seems to synchronize every controller on a session mutex. This might be overkill. But it makes at least controllers thread safe on the session without blocking other users, plus I don't have to worry about synchronization in my controller. But this is still not acceptable for a highly responsive Ajax-GUI.

I get the feeling that there is no general answer to this question and it totally depends on the GUI. If I have plain simple HTML pages where sequential requests are expected `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.setSynchronizeOnSession(true)` seems to be perfect, as I don't have to think about synchronization in my Controllers.

If the GUI becomes more fancy with loads of parallel AJAX-requests I have to take care about synchronization by choosing an eligible mutex.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I'm assuming that you meant to say that the `Cart` bean is Session scoped (your example says that it is request scoped, but that doesn't seem to make sense) and that `CartService` is a singleton.

If we think about how your user interacts with the application, do we actually have a need to perform any synchronization on a `Cart` instance?

We definitely do not need to make `CartService.addItem()` synchronized as we're relying on Spring's proxy injection to ensure that the `Cart` instance from the current Session is injected during the Thread of execution, so no worries there.

So our question of synchronization is about whether there is a scenario during a single Session that requires us to synchronize adding of items to a `Cart`?

I assume that your Session is being driven by the user's browser. There is no way legitimate way to share a single Session between different browsers. So apart from having multiple tabs open, it is highly likely that your user will be adding items to their `Cart` in a sequential manner. Even if they did open multiple tabs and enter items is there a problem? Once the user initiates your "checkout" process, you can block adding more items to the `Cart` and then ask the user to confirm that the `Cart` they are about to checkout is correct, giving them the opportunity to remove any dubious items.

If you still decide that you really need synchronization on the `Cart` then I would do the following:

```
public class Cart
{
     private HashSet<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

     public synchronized void addItem(Item item)
     {
           items.add(item);
     }
}
```

That way you easily synchronize access to the `Set` within the `Cart` class.

Comment: You're assumption was correct. I edited the scope in my question. And I just quickly want to say Yes there are plenty of scenarios where multiple threads access a session scoped bean of one session. Putting the synchronization into the model bean is not really acceptable, as it's more likely to have concurrency issues in the service.